# Is it possible to redirect WHILE sending POST data?

Tags: php, javascript, html

For example, I have a user system that displays a each user's IP address. I want to place a small link on the page next to each IP that will send me to `http://www.whatismyip.com/tools/ip-address-lookup.asp` but POST the IP address, so that I can view it without inputting the IP myself (I'm lazy, what?)

Is this possible with javascript/PHP/HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I 100% understand what you want here but let me give it a try.

You have a list of your users IP-adresses, but want to link them so they're posted to the webpage for a check?

In that case make a form for each IP adress, set the form's action to the whatsmyip-site and make sure you got the IP in a field named the same as the field used for searching the ip on the external site.

So basicly:

```
<form action="http://www.whatismyip.com/tools/ip-address-lookup.asp" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="name_from_site" value="100.0.0.10" />
    <input type="submit" value="Check IP" />
</form>
```

Comment: Shit I don't know why I didn't think of that, thanks. One more question: Would I be able to make it pop up in a new window?

Comment: Ye just add a target="_blank" to the form

Comment: Ye like <form action="http://www.whatismyip.com/tools/ip-address-lookup.asp" method="post" target="_blank">. Worked when I did a quick test on it here now

Comment: Hm, it isn't popping up a new window for me. One moment, I'll check another browser.

Comment: Yep, worked perfectly in internet explorer, Chrome doesn't like it though. Perhaps its my settings. I'll check around.

Comment: Checked it for firefox and IE8, pops a new window in IE and a new tab in FF. Also pops a new tab in Chrome for me (Chrome 8). Could be some popup-blocking or something.

Comment: Yeah, probably. I'll hunt it down. Thanks :]

Answer (score 3):

You can simply make a form that POSTs to the given URL.

```
<form action="http://whatsit.com" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="ip" value="1.2.3.4">
    <input type="submit" value="Go!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript to POST the data (using AJAX techniques) and let the link behave normally.  It'd probably be easiest to attach your JavaScript to the link's onclick event.

Or, you could use the header function from PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/function.header.php

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
   <form action="http://www.whatismyip.com/tools/ip-address-lookup.asp" method="post" name="ip_lookup_form">
        <input type="hidden" name="IP" value="100.0.0.10" />
        <a href="#" onclick="document.ip_lookup_form.submit();">Check out on IP Lookup</a>
    </form>
```